# How to make domain point to another web directory?

Tags: domain

My client gave me limited access to his webserver.   At the moment, I have 2 versions of the same website and they are

```
/home/public_html/

and

/home/public_html/newversion/
```

I want to point mydomain.com from /home/public_html/ to /home/public_html/newversion/

I have acces to the PLESK control panel.  I have ssh access, but it's a non-root account, and i don't think i'm able to access any Apache config files.  I do have the option of using .htaccess files

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given *lots* of assumptions about your configuration, the best bet is probably:

- move everything in /home/public_html to /home/public_html/oldversion
- then move everything from /home/public_html/newversion to /home/public_html

Answer (score 2):

.htaccess file in /home/public_html

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond !newversion
RewriteRule (.*) newversion/$1 [QSA]
```