# How can I configure a NameCheap domain to point to an Apache subfolder?

Tags: apache-2.2, domain

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make domain point to another web directory?](https://serverfault.com/questions/88063/how-to-make-domain-point-to-another-web-directory)

My boss just bought the domain: `sergiotapia.me` for me, and agree'd the host my Wordpress blog on company servers.

We're using Apache (latest version).

The domain is purchased on NameCheap.com and the DNS settings are as follows:

[image]

And when I visit [my URL](http://sergiotapia.me/), it's getting redirected to my VPS server without problems. The thing is, I want my blog to appears at once, not have a user select the folder and then see the blog.

My Wordpress blog is located at: `/var/www/sergiotapia.me`

On IIS, you would need to edit the **Bindings** and map a domain to an application. I'm guessing I have to do something similar on Apache.

What am I looking for here? Any tips on getting this working correctly?

Comment: This question has been answered numerous times here, the above being only one example. Please do at least one search prior to asking your question.

Comment: Like I said, I don't even know what it's called. I obviously searched high and low. Searching is easy if you know what to look for.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: That link doesn't answer my question, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @Serg - sorry but it answers your question exactly. The OP in the other question wants to do *exactly* the same thing you do. Although I prefer [Devin's answer](http://serverfault.com/a/88075/7709) over MikeyB's as Mike's will most likely break your WP installation

Comment: @MarkHenderson: Just tried it following Devin's answer by changing `newversion` to `sergiotapia.me` - please reopen the question so I can get assistance. Thanks!

Comment: @Serg - I suggest that you just ask a new question now that you've tried his solution and it's not working, as it's now a different problem and editing this question would invalidate the answers and comments. There's no problem in asking a new question, just as long as you make sure you relate it to your new problem, not this one (i.e. don't ask the same question again, ask one stating what you tried and that it didn't help)

Answer (score 0):

you need to update your apache configuration files.
Depending how your apache is installed and whether this is the only site on the server; 
start by looking in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (or /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf)
You'll either be changing your overall webroot or adding a vhost.