# Created .htaccess file in /var/www to redirect to folder /var/www/foo

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

*Context: [How can I configure a NameCheap domain to point to an Apache subfolder?](https://serverfault.com/questions/449925/how-can-i-configure-a-namecheap-domain-to-point-to-an-apache-subfolder)*

---

Following [Devin's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/88075/7709) here I've created a `.htaccess` file in `/var/www` and wrote in the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond !sergiotapia.me
RewriteRule (.*) sergiotapia.me/$1 [QSA]
```

My folder structure is such:

```
/var/www/
/var/www/sergiotapia.me
```

When visiting the URL `sergiotapia.me` I see the contents of `/var/www` when I would like to be directly redirected to `/var/www/sergiotapia.me`

Any ideas?

Comment: "When visiting the URL `sergiotapia.me`" - If you actually visit the URL `sergiotapia.me` then no redirect would seem to be necessary? (Assuming the document root is `/var/www`?)

Answer (score 5):

From your question, i think you don't need to use rewrites here, but you should change your DocumentRoot within your VirtualHost block to point to the right directory. So for instance:

```
<VirtualHost sergiotapa.me>
...
DocumentRoot /var/www/sergiotapia.me
...
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your virtual host configuration for `AllowOverride` (Probably within a `<Directory /var/www>` section).

If `AllowOverride None` is set then `.htaccess` is not parsed. Set it to `All` might help...

Answer (score 0):

A `.` in a regular expression is a special character (it means "any character except `\n`"), so you'll need to escape it.

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond !sergiotapia\.me
RewriteRule (.*) sergiotapia\.me/$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: It still doesn't redirect despite escaping the regex. Do you think I need to restart the Apache service first? Edit: Restarted service and still no dice. :(

Comment: "`RewriteCond !sergiotapia\.me`" - this directive is not even valid ("bad argument") and would result in a 500 error if processed at all.